# Reading pdf file in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to read a local PDF file in PhoneGap. I have tried the following code, but the in-app browser is displaying nothing.

```
var ref = window.open('./1342172154.pdf', '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    alert('start: ' + event.url);
});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    alert('stop: ' + event.url);
});
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {
    alert('error: ' + event.message);
});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
    alert(event.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fileopener plugin.
this plugin use to open file using native app in android

https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener

Comment: thanks for reply,but i want to open pdf file within app not with external app

Answer (score 0):

use childBrowser plugin -
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser
this is useful in most phonegap and cordovaapp

Comment: thanks for reply,but child browser is not displaying pdf file